# Firebase Firestore Web NOT working behind corporate proxy

Tags: firebase, proxy, google-cloud-firestore

My computer is behind a corporate proxy. While visiting a website which is using Firebase Firestore, it is not connecting to the firebase servers. I am getting the below error in console.

```
[2018-09-21T10:09:15.854Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.4.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

How to work with Firestore web behind proxy?

Note: If the system is not behind proxy, same code is working fine. So no issues with the code, but how to setup proxy info in firestore?

Comment: It seems we have asked the same question about the same time. Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52441316/firestore-grpc-behind-a-corporate-firewall-proxy

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which framework you are using Firestore will access a number of domains under `googleapis.com` over port 443.

If you're proxy is inspecting https traffic then you will most likely have to whitelist `https://*.googleapis.com/`.